# Boot desktop from laptop connected by USB

Tags: boot, desktop, laptop

1. Would it be possible to have laptop with some Linux, that I would be able to connect to any desktop with USB-USB cable, and boot something from that laptop? (its actual OS or something different dedicated to this kind of activity - with more generic configuration for hardware)
2. If yes, how would you achieve this?

I think it should be possible considering you can boot system from USB device, so you theoretically should be able to trick desktop to think that you are actually a boot device - am I wrong?

Also, [Ubuntu for Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android) seems to be something like that. But how hard would it be to achieve with custom OS and custom device that runs Linux?

Comment: You're asking if you can use the laptop as a USB mounted HDD which would allow you to boot desktop systems from the laptop, right?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but not likely to work with your laptop's built in USB connectors. Those connectors are wired to be "masters" ( or "hosts") and what you would need is a USB "slave" ( or "client", "device" ) connector and appropriate software.

It is not just the connector (or a USB-A USB-A cable), the USB chip connected to that connector that 'talks USB' is much more important. And unless that chip is really dumb (which is not usual and would put a strain on your CPU) you cannot solve this in software on your laptop.

What you need is some  device like an Arduino that have two slave USB connections. You could make a (very) smart cable out of such a device that talks to the other machine as if it were a USB drive ("slave"). It would communicate with your laptop as a slave as well via some protocol to get the appropriate data whenever there is a data request from the other machine.

Comment: So it is impossible to make usb master controller act as slave and I would always need something in the middle with usb slave controller?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK most controllers implement handshaking etc on the chip (to relieve the CPU burden), you cannot reverse that unless you have a special controller chip or handle all that in the CPU (but it is not wired to do so).

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking this question:

> Can you use a laptop as a USB mounted HDD which would allow you to boot desktop systems from the laptop?

Then the answer would be no. That isn't possible. If you look at a system's BIOS it typically lists the methods that you can use to boot it. Even though it lists USB as one of these methods, you can't typically access another system's HDD via it's USB bus in a manner that would allow you to boot another system.

#### Alternatives

I would recommend buying an inexpensive USB thumbdrive and setting up multiple distros on that device instead. There are a variety of tools that will help you in building such a setup.

Tools such as [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) can assist in setting up such a USB device. You can also use [UBCD - Ultimate Boot CD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110206/7453) to create CD/DVDs as well that are loaded with as many distros as you can cram on a disk.

#### Multiple live distros

Lastly there is this script called `multicd` which can help in the construction of a USB thumbdrive which can contain multiple distros. This blog post covers the details of setting this up and using it, titled: [Create Multi Live Linux Distro in single CD/DVD](http://jeysundar.blogspot.com/2009/05/multi-live-distro-in-single-cddvd.html).

The script is available from this website, [MultiCD - Combine several CDs into one.](http://multicd.tuxfamily.org/) as well as [Github](https://github.com/IsaacSchemm/multicd). After setting this up you'll be able to boot a system using the thumbdrive and you'll get a dialog similar to this:

[image: ss #1]